# How to access the REST service url in the REST Client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, appfuse

I have developed web-service application using app-fuse frame work
But I couldn't reach the service url
admin authentication username :admin and password :admin 
and here no any Oauth configuration

my service url is : **http:// :8080/ims-web/services/api/gencodes/getGencodeByDistType**

Under the Response header I got the message like that
Status Code: **500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: There must be some exception in server logs. Check those.

Comment: 500 could be anything wrong at server side. As @HimanshuBhardwaj says, check logs for exceptions.